# Ionic - save picture to device with a specific filename

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I'm working on an Ionic/Cordova application.
I want to take pictures and save them on my device. I managed to do it but I don't really know how to give a specific filename (instead of having a '*IMG_20200903...*' filename).

How could I do ?
Here is the snippet :

```
gallery(){

  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 20,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true        
  }
  
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
   this.clickedImagePath = imageData;
  }, (err) => {
    alert(err);
  });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Ionic Capacitor:

You can use ionic FileSystemApi to write the file with custom name. [Ionic FileSystem API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/3-saving-photos#filesystem-api)

```
private async savePicture(cameraPhoto: CameraPhoto) {
  // Convert photo to base64 format, required by Filesystem API to save
  const base64Data = await this.readAsBase64(cameraPhoto);

  // Write the file to the data directory
  const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
  const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: fileName,
    data: base64Data,
    directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data
  });

  // Use webPath to display the new image instead of base64 since it's
  // already loaded into memory
  return {
    filepath: fileName,
    webviewPath: cameraPhoto.webPath
  };
}
```

2. Using Ionic Native.

You can use [Camera](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera) & [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) plugins to write the file with custom name.

```
    //here injecting camera and file class to our component part as object  
    constructor(private camera: Camera, private file: File) {}  
    
    //here this method is used to start a camera and take a picture and save a picture in specific mentioned part.  
    public getPicture() {  
        let base64ImageData;  
        const options: CameraOptions = {  
            //here is the picture quality in range 0-100 default value 50. Optional field  
            quality: 100,  
            /**here is the format of an output file. 
             *destination type default is FILE_URI. 
                * DATA_URL: 0 (number) - base64-encoded string,  
                * FILE_URI: 1 (number)- Return image file URI, 
                * NATIVE_URI: 2 (number)- Return image native URI        
                */  
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,  
            /**here is the returned image file format 
             *default format is JPEG 
                * JPEG:0 (number), 
                * PNG:1 (number), 
                */  
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,  
            /** Only works when Picture Source Type is PHOTOLIBRARY or  SAVEDPHOTOALBUM.  
             *PICTURE: 0 allow selection of still pictures only. (DEFAULT) 
                *VIDEO: 1 allow selection of video only.        
                */  
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,  
            /**here set the source of the picture 
             *Default is CAMERA.  
                *PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,  
                *CAMERA : 1,  
                *SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2 
                */  
            sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA  
        }  
        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {  
            //here converting a normal image data to base64 image data.  
            base64ImageData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;  
            /**here passing three arguments to method 
            *Base64 Data 

            *Folder Name 

            *File Name 
            */  
            this.writeFile(base64ImageData, “My Picture”, “sample.jpeg”);  
        }, (error) => {  
            console.log('Error Occured: ' + error);       
        });  
    }  
    //here is the method is used to write a file in storage  
    public writeFile(base64Data: any, folderName: string, fileName: any) {  
        let contentType = this.getContentType(base64Data);  
        let DataBlob = this.base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType);  
        // here iam mentioned this line this.file.externalRootDirectory is a native pre-defined file path storage. You can change a file path whatever pre-defined method.  
        let filePath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + folderName;  
        this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, DataBlob, contentType).then((success) => {  
            console.log("File Writed Successfully", success);  
        }).catch((err) => {  
            console.log("Error Occured While Writing File", err);  
        })  
    }  
    //here is the method is used to get content type of an bas64 data  
    public getContentType(base64Data: any) {  
        let block = base64Data.split(";");  
        let contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];  
        return contentType;  
    }  
    //here is the method is used to convert base64 data to blob data  
    public base64toBlob(b64Data, contentType) {  
        contentType = contentType || '';  
        sliceSize = 512;  
        let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);  
        let byteArrays = [];  
        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {  
            let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);  
            let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);  
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {  
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);  
            }  
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);  
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);  
        }  
        let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {  
            type: contentType  
        });  
        return blob;  
    }
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I guess the `CameraPhoto` is related to Capacitor (@capacitor/core). How to make it without Capacitor and `CameraPhoto` ?

Comment: Great ! I tried but there's one error at the line `let DataBlob = this.base64toBlob(content, contentType);`. The error is `cannot find name content`

Comment: That should be base64Data.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried the code : the camera was active, a photo was shot but didn't seem to be downloaded into the device (maybe I don't know where I should look but I didn't find it).

Comment: As per the code, check the console for success status ("File Writed Successfully"). If this works then check your externalRootDirectory contains folder name "My Picture" If that exists then your image will be saved there.